# How do I enable desktop visual effects?

Tags: nvidia, compiz, effects

I have lenovo g460 with VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310M] (rev a2) grapics card

I have install the driver using `gksudo jockey-gtk` command, but when I change the visual effects to extra its give me 'Desktop effects could not be enabled'. I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Is jockey-gtk the tool that the "HArdware Drivers" GUI uses?  Or is it something seperate.

Answer (score 2):

First go to console (ALT+F2 then type `gnome-terminal`). Inside the console type nvidia and press the TAB button. If you have the nvidia drivers correctly install there should appear several nvidia files (Like nvidia-settings, nvidia-xconfig, etc..)

Type `nvidia-xconfig` so it edits the xorg.conf file with the nvidia configs. Reboot the PC.

If you can not still have special effects then do the following:
nvidia-current

1. Install mesa-utils (`sudo aptitude install mesa-utils` or `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`)
2. Type `glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"`. If a NO appears then there is some problem with your nvidia installs. If a YES appears then typing `compiz --replace` after pressing ALT+F2 should give you the 3D effects.
3. If the NO appeared just try to reinstall the drivers with `sudo aptitude reinstall 
   nvidia-current`
4. Lastly type `dmesg | grep "nvidia"` in console to see if there is an output regarding nvidia. Normally the output will say how to fix it.

Comment: I Have the same problem and CYREX's advice worked, but when i log out and back in the effects are gone again?? Any idea how i keep them the way they are without having to redo the "compiz --replace"? TYVM :-)

Answer (score -1):

Following instructions given by CYREX, in order to manage easily visual effect, I would suggest to install  [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/). Than from Ubuntu Tweak check 'Install Simple Desktop Effect Setting Manager'. Run application from System/Preferences/Simple CompizConfig Settings Manager.
[image: Ubuntu Tweak 0.5.7]

Comment: -1 - Ubuntu Tweak is dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Hello James ! I think, any operating system is dangerous for people who has no idea how to use it :)

Comment: I agree that it is better not to use Ubuntu tweaks in 11.04. Unfortunately, I had so many annoying "features" in 11.04 so I did a downgrade to 10.10 - now everything works well :)

Comment: Agreed there! However, Ubuntu tweak makes it *dangerously* easy to mess up your system - in my experience, it's pretty hard to mess it up without trying to - but Ubuntu tweak exposes a lot of snares that can get you into real trouble. :)

Answer (score -2):

you may want to try my solution:

add "compiz --replace" to your "startup applications" menu.

I did, and it works.