# How do I enable visual effects my desktop?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

Using Ubuntu 10.10, I am having some issues with enabling the visual effects on my system. It doesn't allow me to use the normal & the extra options. It checks for the drivers then it says that the driver is not found.

My laptop model is Compaq PresarioV2000.

How do I enable the visual effects?

Comment: Please give us details on the graphic card your laptop uses. You can find out by typing `lspci` in a terminal.

Comment: What have you mean by Desktop visual Effects ?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your graphics card (Intel GM855 I guess) is not too well supported from the kernel in Ubuntu 10.10 (see [Intel 8xx Issues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Mavericki8xxStatus)). To get an idea on how to solve issues you may also have a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9962191) from Ubuntuforums.

Downloading drivers from a manufacturer website is not recommended for unexperienced users. It is only rarely needed anyway. You would need a **detailed** how-to for the installation process and an additional proof from the community that it's really working with your Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1):

You already check the *System* / *Administration* / **Additional Drivers**?

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 recently and, even though I am using the most recent (version 173) of the NVidia drivers for my Nvidia Geforce 6200, it still wont let me enable desktop effects.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

try downloading the drivers form the company website (  i mean laptop company)

some more links relating similar queries are:

[How do I enable desktop visual effects?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17578/how-do-i-enable-desktop-visual-effects)

Comment: Downloading will not help.