# Where's the screen to enable/disable 3d visual effects?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, 3d, effects

I just upgraded from 11.4 to 11.10 and my desktop effects (like wobbly windows) are gone (they are still enabled in the compiz-config thingy).

So I'm looking for the window/screen that would let me enable/disable visual effects, but can not seem to find it.

Where the heck is that screen in Oneiric?

Thanx.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17578/how-do-i-enable-desktop-visual-effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are still in the same place in 11.10 as in 11.04. The difference is this:

In 11.04 Compiz visual effects such as wobbly windows clashed with the Unity interface and removed the top panel with the app-indicators.

In 11.10 the Compiz window and compositing manager is better integrated with Unity. You can now enable wobbly windows. I know. I have done so just this week. I cannot speak for any other of the effects. But you specifically mention wobbly windows.

What do you mean by "oneiric?" It can mean: 11.10 + Unity 3D or 11.10 + Unity 2D or 11.10 + Gnome shell or even 11.10 + Gnome shell fall back mode (no special effects). With questions like your one a person needs to give more information about their set up. Do you need to use a proprietary driver to get enhanced effects?

I suggest:

1) Go to Additional Drivers and confirm that any proprietary driver (if needed) is activated.

2) Install CompizConfigSettingsManager.

3) Enable the Ubuntu Unity plugin in the Compiz Settings Manager.

4) Reboot.

5) Open Compiz Settings Manager and try to activate one of the visual effects like wobbly windows.

With some of the effects in compiz you should be prepared for the screen to blank as the old setting is replaced with the new setting.

Oh, by the way, you find Compiz Configuration Settings Manager by opening the Dash (click the Ubuntu icon at the top of the Launcher) and you type compiz in the search panel and an icon for compiz settings manager will appear which you can click to load the compiz settings manager.

You may have noticed that System Settings is less crowded than in 11.04. The Dash has some lens that effectively replaced the old Applications, Places and Administration/Preferences menus in 10.10.

I find it difficult to understand what you want information about.

Regards.

Comment: Apparently my Intel HD 3000 integrated graphics adapter is no longer installed in 11.10, therefore the effects are gone.

Comment: @PouriaMel I had trouble on most my machines with the GPUs during 11.10. I just stayed on 11.04 with most of them, then when 12.04 came out I upgrade them all twice. It was broke at 11.10, but worked again at 12.04.